# Sending a complex object as parameter to Asp.Net PageMethod

Tags: asp.net, jquery, vb.net, pagemethods

I am trying to send an object created in JavaScript to an ASP.NET PageMethod. This object mirrors the properties of an existing custom business object, so i was hoping that i could pass a single object instead of a parameter for each property. I am getting an error "Unknown web method SavePart when attempting to use this method.

Javascript:

```
function() {
    var pt = { Id: 1, Onhand: 20, LowPoint: 30, __type: 'Custom.Objects.Part'};

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'partlist.aspx/SavePart',
        data: JSON.stringify(pt),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset: utf-8;'
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(results) { alert('Success!'); }
    });
}
```

Code Behind:

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function SavePart(pt as Custom.Objects.Part) as Boolean
    Dim repo as new PartRepository()
    return repo.Save(pt)
End Function
```

I am using another PageMethod which just accepts an int, and this works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up solving my problem by sending the object this way through the jQuery ajax command:

```
data: '{"pt":' + JSON.stringify(pt) + '}'
```

this serialized the object automatically and returned it to my WebMethod. When i tried sending the object as is, i got an error saying "invalid JSON primitive".

Comment: Ah... that actually makes sense. Just sending pt probably caused the deserializer to attempt to pass each property of the object to the webmethod as separate parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to pass a string to the method. You will need to accept the string, and deserialize it with fx. [JavascriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) or [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is incredibly old, but its not very intuitive when you're using this to figure out what the issues are. You are very close but I wanted to add a bit more to this in case someone else later wants to do the same thing. This works with nested objects as well, the one thing I can say is CASE matters in your JS variables that map to .NET POCOs on the page method.

Your "answer" is where I will start with. And as in the comments below it, yes you have to pass the *object* wrapped in its **page method variable name**.

Ill say it again, this is CASE-Sensitive, and can trip you up not just on the *object's* name but its properties as well. So to combat this I usually create my POCO object in .NET then copy that to the page so I know the names, capitalization and all are correct. 
Something like this:

POCO:

```
Public Class CustomObject
    Public Property Id as integer
    Public Property ReqDate as DateTime
    Public Property Message as string
End Sub
```

Now with a defined POCO for page method, replicate that "model" exactly as it is for the JS/AJAX to post with, being vigilant about case-sensitivity.

```
function ParseAndPostData()
{
   var data = { custobj: {
                Id: 1, 
                ReqDate: "04/12/2018",
                Message:"Hello!" 
                }
           };
  //Stringify the data so it goes through page method parser
  var postdata = JSON.stringify(data);
  $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: '/BasePath/SomePage.aspx/SomeMethod',
         data: postdata,
         contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
         dataType: 'json',
         success: function (msg) {
              var parsedACData = JSON.parse(msg.d);
              alert(parsedACData);
             },
        error: function (msg) {
              alert(msg);
              }
  });
}
```

Page Method (Note *custobj* in the parameters):

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function PostCustomObject(custobj as CustomObject) as String
    return custobj.Message
End Function
```